# What is a "path_expression" in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, lexical-analysis

BigQuery describes a [`path_expression`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#path_expressions) in the Syntax page as follows:

> A path expression describes how to navigate to an object in a graph of objects and generally follows this structure...

> Examples:
>
> ```
> foo.bar
> foo.bar/25
> foo/bar:25
> foo/bar/25-31
> /foo/bar
> /25/foo/bar
> ```

What are some actual examples of a Path Expression with a valid table, for example in a CTE? My thinking was that a path expression would be something that explicitly qualifies a field or struct sub-field, such as:

```
myTable.myField.mySubfield
```

But from the above syntax, which allows for:

```
/:-
```

I'm not exactly sure what it is or how it would be used. Could someone show a real-world example of how a path expression would be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path expressions describe where to search for (or store) data. Consider [this example from the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/introduction#sql):

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  weight_pounds, state, year, gestation_weeks
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:samples.natality]
ORDER BY
  weight_pounds DESC
LIMIT
  10;
```

In this example, the portion `[bigquery-public-data:samples.natality]` is the `path_expression`.
It is saying to look at the `natality` table in the `samples` database in the `bigquery-public-data` project.

> But from the above syntax, which allows for: `/:-`

This would actually **not** be allowed, as a `path_expression`.

This example would be parsed as:

```
/:-

{first_part}/{subsequent_part}:{subsequent_part}

{{ unquoted_identifier | quoted_identifier }} / 
{{ unquoted_identifier | quoted_identifier | number }} : 
{{ unquoted_identifier | quoted_identifier | number }}
```

An [`unquoted_identifier`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#unquoted_identifiers) must at least begin with a letter or an underscore. A [`quoted_identifier`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#quoted_identifiers) can contain any character, but cannot be empty. The empty string therefore cannot be considered an `unquoted_identifier`, `quoted_identifier`, or `number`, so this expression is invalid (and is invalid in 3 positions).

A possible minimal `path_expression` could be something like:

```
a:b.c
```

meaning look in the `c` table in the `b` database in the `a` project.

Comment: This example is written in BigQuery Legacy SQL syntax. But the path expressions are documented as part of the new Google Standard SQL syntax. Is that example still valid with new syntax?

Comment: Answering by myself: No, this isn't valid syntax in Google Standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but I think you are confusing `Path Expression` (as it is defined in referenced documentation) with something like (for example) JSONPath.
In my mind, the the former is just terminology that introduced in order to have consistent reference within the documentation, while later (obviously) is query language for JSON, similar to XPath for XML, etc.

So, if you would asked for something like JSONPath use - I bet you would get tones of usage examples, but asking about `Path Expression use` has not much chances to gather answers even having hefty bounty as it is ONLY used in that documentation.

Comment: You are mistaken. JSONPath syntax is different and is described elsewhere in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#JSONPath_format