# How are Path Expressions used in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, syntax

BigQuery documentation describes [path expressions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#path_expressions), which look like this:

```
foo.bar
foo.bar/25
foo/bar:25
foo/bar/25-31
/foo/bar
/25/foo/bar
```

But it doesn't say a lot about how and where these path expressions are used. It only briefly mentions:

> A path expression describes how to navigate to an object in a graph of objects.

- But what is this graph of objects?
- How would you use this syntax with a graph of objects?
- What's the meaning of a path expression like `foo/bar/25-31`?

My question is: **what are these Path Expressions the official documentation describes?**

I've searched through BigQuery docs but haven't managed to find any other mention of these path expressions. **Is this syntax actually part of BigQuery SQL at all?**

### What I've found out so far

There is an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73188154/what-is-a-path-expression-in-bigquery), which asks roughly the same thing, but for some reason it's downvoted and none of the answers are correct. Though the question it asks is more about a specific detail of the path expression syntax.

Anyway, the answers there propose a few hypotheses as to what path expressions are:

**It's not a syntax for referencing tables**

The BigQuery Legacy SQL uses syntax that's similar to path expressions for referencing tables:

```
SELECT state, year FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.natality]
```

But that syntax is only valid in BigQuery Legacy SQL. In the new Google Standard SQL it produces a syntax error. There's a separate documentation for [table path syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#table_path), which is different from path expression syntax.

**It's not JSONPath syntax**

[JSONPath](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#JSONPath_format) syntax is documented elsewhere and looks like:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(json_text, '$.class.students[0]')
```

**It's not a syntax for accessing JSON object graph**

There's a separate [JSON subscript operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#json_subscript_operator) syntax, which looks like so:

```
SELECT json_value.class.students[0]['name']
```

### My current hypothesis

My best guess is that BigQuery doesn't actually support such syntax, and the description in the docs is a mistake.

But please, prove me wrong. I'd really like to know because I'm trying to write a parser for BigQuery SQL, and to do so, I need to understand the whole syntax that BigQuery allows.

Comment: Can you clarify more on the issue you're facing? To use select statement in Standard SQL you will have to use the syntax `Select Column from 'Project.Dataset.Table'`. JSON_VALUE can be used as for eg: `SELECT json_value.class.students[0]['name'] AS first_student
FROM table` and JSON_QUERY can be used as `SELECT JSON_QUERY(json, '$."a.x"'), JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$['a.x']")
FROM table;` in Standard SQL. Graph objects are built to represent complex relationships.

Comment: My question is: what are these "Path Expressions" that the official BigQuery documentation describes? I don't have a problem with writing a SELECT statement or using JSON functions and values - I only mentioned these to clarify that these are NOT the answers to my question.

Comment: People who worked with SQL before are familar to `Select * from Dataset.TableName`. In BigQuery this is a bit more comples with `Project.Dataset.Tablename`. Also fields can be nested or contain subelements. For explaining these special notification, the "path expression" is introduced. But only part of it is possible to be used in BigQuery. ":" and "-" and "/" are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a "path expression" is the combination of identifiers that points to specific objects/tables/columns/etc.  So `` `project.dataset.table.struct.column` `` is a path expression comprising of 5 identifiers. I also think that `alias.column` within the context of a query is a path expression with 2 identifiers (although the alias is probably expanded behind the scenes).

If you scroll up a bit in your link, there is a [section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#identifier_examples) with some examples of valid path expressions, which also happens to be right after the `identifiers` section.

With this in mind, I think a JSON path expression is a certain type of path expression, as parsing JSON requires a specific set of identifiers to get to a specific data element.

As for the "graph" terminology, perhaps BQ parses the query and accesses data using a graph methodology behind the scenes, I can't really say.  I would guess "path expressions" probably makes more sense to the team working *on* BigQuery rather than users using BigQuery. I don't think there is any special syntax for you to "use" path expressions.

If you are writing a parser, maybe take some inspiration from this [ZetaSQL parser](https://github.com/google/zetasql/blob/master/zetasql/parser/bison_parser.y), which has several references to path expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree it would make sense for path expressions to mean the syntax of `ident1.ident2.ident3.etc`. That's also the syntax that a path_expression rule describes in ZetaSQL grammar. However, it provides no explanation for the syntax that BigQuery documentation describes, notably the use of `/`, `:`, `-` characters inside path expressions.

Comment: It's quite possible that's is how BQ operates internally, or perhaps it refers to planned features that never made it to production, or could be for backward compatibility, or for a variety of other reasons .  `/`s could easily be something where you can query against a file/folder structure in GCP.  `:`s were used in LegacySQL as noted. `-` (and `:` for that matter) could be used to get to an element in a YAML file perhaps.  Whatever you are trying to do with this information, I wouldn't worry too much.  Worry about the 99% use-case and come back to it if needed.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty. Although it didn't directly answer my question, it provided pointers to resources I found helpful, and they guided me towards a possible answer and better understanding of the BigQuery ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks this syntax comes from [ZetaSQL parser](https://github.com/google/zetasql), which includes [the exact same documentation](https://github.com/google/zetasql/blob/master/docs/lexical.md#path-expressions). BigQuery most likely uses ZetaSQL internally as its parser (ZetaSQL supports all of BigQuery syntax and they're both from Google).

According to [ZetaSQL grammar](https://github.com/google/zetasql/blob/master/zetasql/parser/bison_parser.y#L5263) a path expression beginning with `/` and containing `:` and `-` can be used for referencing tables in FROM clause. Looks like the `/` and `:` are simply part of identifier names, like the `-` is part of identifier names in BigQuery.

But the support for the `:` and `/` characters in ZetaSQL path expressions can be toggled on or off, and it seems that in BigQuery it's been toggled off. BigQuery doesn't allow `:` and `/` characters in table names - not even when they're quoted.

ZetaSQL also allows to toggle the support of `-` in identifier names, which BigQuery does allow.

**My conclusion:** it's a ZetaSQL parser feature, the documentation of which has been mistakenly copy-pasted to BigQuery documentation.

*Thanks to [rtenha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74599049/15982) for pointing out the ZetaSQL parser, of which I wasn't aware before.*